# How to get items using PR_SEARCH_KEY in folder.items.Restrict using redemption

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I got  PR_SEARCH_KEY from mailitem using redemption and value is PT_Binary format. i do not know how to convert it to string using redemption in C#.

I tried to search items from folder. My code for getting  PR_SEARCH_KEY is

```
     string PR_SEARCH_KEY = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102";
     var searchKeyValue= mailItem.Fields[PR_SEARCH_KEY];
```

I tried to execute

```
var existingItem = folder.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

but i do not know how to create filter string from searchkey value.

I read some post and they are converting to string and then use as usual way to create it using redemption.
I need someone help to get item from folder.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I updated my code by adding double quote  in filter variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You woudl need to specify the DASL name (quoted) along with the hex representation of the value:

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102" = '10ABF5...'
```

Comment: I generate hex using this code  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(current.Length * 2);
                                foreach (byte b in searchKeyValue)
                                    hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                                string result = hex.ToString();    and pass filter value as "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102='3103B439E96AD7438891A820FF4DED30' "

Comment: it is not working giving error  Unknown property name: http

Comment: I have upload screenshot in description. Please review it

Comment: the DASL name needs to be quoted.